# Mapping a java Entity to a GraphQL object

Tags: java, hibernate, graphql, graphql-java

I have difficulty in implementing GraphQL in a java project as a part of updating it. I'm trying to connect an entity (which uses the Hibernate ORM to map to different databases) to a GraphQLObjectType . Any suggestions how can I accomplish this? Can I omit the GraphQL database configurations if so?

Comment: anything new on this matter? Searching now for the same.

Comment: Hello, @cingulata! You can use https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations or you can implement something like this yourself which does the same work.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this question, this page probably has the most up to date for CODE FIRST schema generation: https://github.com/graphql-java/awesome-graphql-java

Answer (score 10):

There're multiple options here.

- It's probably [best to not even map an entity directly](https://thoughts-on-java.org/dont-expose-entities-in-api/) . Entities are direct representations of the DB and, as such, should probably not be directly exposed, but wrapped into DTOs (maybe allowing pagination, flattening relations, or whatever is appropriate) instead.
- If you just need to map the class (entity or not) to a `GraphQLObjectType`, [graphql-java-annotations](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations) is the simplest (and most limited) route (check the status of this project first, it was on a hiatus for a while)
- If you want to expose the entire entity graph through GraphQL, [graphql-jpa](https://github.com/jcrygier/graphql-jpa) might be your best bet (as [Sriram suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43690155/294657)), as it's intended to do exactly that, while also adding pagination, aggregation and sorting
- If you want to automatically expose not only an entity/DTO class, but also the operations upon it (e.g. an arbitrary service class), look at [graphql-spqr](https://github.com/leangen/GraphQL-SPQR) (I'm the author of that project)

Answer (score 1):

If you already defined your entities using JPA/Hibernate, try this:

https://github.com/jcrygier/graphql-jpa